# Serialize related models in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have django models that are simplified as:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ClientDetail(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business_format = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    def __str__(self):
        return "Details for {}".format(self.client.name)


class ClientAssignment(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return "Assignment: {} for Client: {}".format(self.assignment.name, self.client.name)

class Assignment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am using `django-rest-framework` and would like to create a view where I can provide `client_id` and receive a serialized object that contains all 3 related models. I tried using PrimaryKeyRelatedField as follows but I'm not sure if I'm using this correctly.

```
class CompleteClientObject(ModelSerializer):
    assignment = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=ClientAssignment.objects)
    detail = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=ClientDetail.objects)
    client = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Client)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ("id", "name", "detail", "assignment",)
```

How can I achieve this using serializers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your serializer fields you can use the `source` argument to specify a field on the model.   If you're trying to access the reverse relation from the Client model you should be using the `MODELNAME_set` field on as your source.  This field is added to the other end of a ForeignKey by Django.  I.e.

```
assignment = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    source='clientassignment_set',
    many=True,
    read_only=True,
)
```

Note that with `read_only=True` you don't need to specify a queryset either.

Your other choice would be to specify a `related_name` field on your ForeignKey's which overrides the `MODELNAME_set` auto-generated fields, and set these to "assignment" and "detail".

Comment: What would my `Meta.model` property be? `Client`?

Comment: That's correct, your Metal.model would still be Client.

Comment: This gives me a `'Client' object has no attribute 'assignment'` error. I assume this is since the base `Client` model doesn't have a `assignment` field

Comment: That is why you should be using the source attribute on your assignment serializer field to specify that the assign serializer field should use the `clientassignment_set` field on the model

Comment: This gives me a `Object of type 'RelatedManager' is not JSON serializable` error which I'm not sure how to solve.